# Issues connecting to azure virtual machines using public IP address

Tags: sockets, azure, tcp, ip, azure-virtual-machine

I have the following virtual machines setup

> **VM1** redis, rabbitmq, open ports 6379, 5672
>
> **VM2** app server, celery
>
> **VM3** mysql open port 3306

Now the issue is that sometimes app server is not able to connect to all these open ports on these machine using public ip but other times it just works fine.

I was able to replicate the issue with mysql-client and redis-cli so it doesn't look like app server issue.

Connection establishment gets failed. However at the same time If I connect to the same host from my local system or some other VM it works.

All machines are running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

I also did a trace route and I was able to get trace route for two situation (**connected**/**not able to connect**)

**Case when connection is established.**

```
azureuser@vm2:~$ tcptraceroute vm3 6379

Selected device eth0, address local_ip, port 48950 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to vm3 on TCP port 6379 , 30 hops max

 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  vm3 [open]  1.338 ms  1.540 ms  1.216 ms
```

**Case when connection is not getting established.**

```
azureuser@vm2:~$ tcptraceroute vm3 6379                                 
Selected device eth0, address local_ip, port 42141 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to vm3 on TCP port 6379 , 30 hops max

 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
Destination not reached
```

I also tried connecting via ssh tunneling but I get the same result.

**UPDATE:** After downgrading to 12.04 I am not seeing this issue anymore.
Rohitash